# How to override a template file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to override final_price.phtml  template file located at /vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/base/templates/product/price/

How should i do that?

Comment: Hi @Steven, It may sound straight forward but have you tried it doing through your theme?

Comment: No i did not get how to do. as it is coming from base folder

Answer (score 0):

This works the same regardless of whether the template is initially in frontend or base, so in this instance create a file with the same name inside `app/design/frontend/{yourVendor}/{yourTheme}/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/price`